# C# handling multiple events for an Event

Tags: c#, winforms, eventhandler

I have a static class to handler MS SQL database interaction with an eventhandler like this:

```
public static event EventHandler<SQLExceptionEventArgs> SQLExceptionCaught;
```

then I have a function to handle it:

```
 private static void OnSQLExceptionCaught(SqlException e)
{
    if (SQLExceptionCaught != null)
    {
        SQLExceptionCaught(SQLExceptionCaught.Target, new SQLExceptionEventArgs(e));
    }
}
```

I also have a custom form inherited from Windows.Forms.Form which adds a delegate to that event handler:

```
DBHandler.SQLExceptionCaught += this.handleSQLException;
```

(it's removed when form is closing)

and then this delegate is overriden in each form.

It works fine when only one form is open, but I cannot make it work for multiple forms so it only fires the delegate from the form that actually fired the event.

Would you please point me to the right direction on that? Is it even possible?

I'd gladly consider any other solution as long as it preserve this functionality.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You can't really do that with a single global DB handler, unless you pass the form with every single query / command. In fact, that's exactly the point where you're sending `SQLExceptionCaught.Target`, rather than the actual *sender*. If every single query / command passes the sender (the actual form that caused that query to execute), you could just compare the sender to `this` in the handler, and know whether it's "your" exception or not. But you'd probably rather want to keep a separate instance of the DB handler anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you should turn your static class into a non-static class. Then you'd have an *instance* event, and two instances of the class (one per form). At that point, the two event handlers would be appropriately separated. Fundamentally, you're sharing inappropriately at the moment.

As an aside, your current code can throw a `NullReferenceException` due to the value of `SQLExceptionCaught` becoming null after the check but before the next line. Typically you'd fix this using a local variable:

```
private static void OnSQLExceptionCaught(SqlException e)
{
    var handler = SQLExceptionCaught;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(SQLExceptionCaught.Target, new SQLExceptionEventArgs(e));
    }
}
```

There are other options around extension methods and the null conditional operator introduced in C# 6... see [my blog post on the topic](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the problem as folows:

- Open multiple forms.
- Set a breakpoint in your `OnSQLExceptionCaught`.
- At that point, check the content of the event `SQLExceptionCaught`, using the method `GetInvocationList`. If it has only one form as a subscriber, check your code which is subscribing to your event.
- It there are more than one subscribers, and only one subscriber is called, make sure that subscriber does NOT throw an exception. If an exception is thrown during the invocation of an event, the other subscribers are not getting called.